# Shrinking very large If statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a  situation where I have 4 variables named eax,ebx,ecx and edx, and any one of them may be set to any of these vars: var1,var,var3 and var4, however they are set as the string "varx" instead of the value of varx, but only one of them will every  need fixing at a time. I have been using this if  statement:

```
  if eax=="var1":
    eax=var1
  elif ebx=="var1":
    ebx=var1
  elif ecx=="var1":
    ecx=var1
  elif edx=="var1":
    edx=var1
  elif eax=="var2":
    eax=var2
  elif ebx=="var2":
    ebx=var2
  elif ecx=="var2":
    ecx=var2
  elif edx=="var2":
    edx=var2
  elif eax=="var3":
    eax=var3
  elif ebx=="var3":
    ebx=var3
  elif ecx=="var3":
    ecx=var3
  elif edx=="var3":
    edx=var3
  elif eax=="var4":
    eax=var4
  elif ebx=="var4":
    ebx=var4
  elif ecx=="var4":
    ecx=var4
  elif edx=="var4":
    edx=var4
```

But I am aware that this is very bad practise. Is there a way for me to compact this if statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the right place to learn fundamental programming techniques.

Comment: Normally I would use a switch, but python does not have them. I do not know where to learn these fundamental techniques. If you could redirect me to a place to learn these, I would be grateful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It seems like a specific, on-topic question. I'm not sure it matters that it's at a beginner level.

Comment: The problem you have isn't that you lack a "switch statement"; the problem is that you have a bunch of variable names and you want to do something similar after choosing the appropriate variable name. Try to think of a data structure you have heard of that can store all the related values together, associating names to values; and try to think of a way to repeat the common process of checking each name.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon The problem with these kinds of questions is that a large number of beginners will have the same underlying misconception or blind spot, that leads to a large number of subtly different questions with completely different contexts. All of these are unhelpful to the next beginner in line, because they won't be easily searched up. And marking as a duplicate often doesn't work because a) there might just not be a canonical dupe and b) the beginner would never guess what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try thinking about the update process for a single variable at a time and create a function to handle that. Then the logic can be easily reused for each variable. This means you'll have a function that handles 4 (or 5) cases and call it 4 times (resulting in 8-9 steps) instead of having to do each combination (16 steps). This also has the benefit of making your code more readable and maintainable.

For example:

```py
def get_var(x):
    if x == "var1":
        return var1
    if x == "var2":
        return var2
    if x == "var3":
        return var3
    if x == "var4":
        return var4
    return x

eax = get_var(eax)
ebx = get_var(ebx)
ecx = get_var(ecx)
edx = get_var(edx)
```

Note this is basically a switch statement (which is not supported by Python), and can instead be written in the following way (which can be easier to update depending on the rest of your code):

```py
vars_lookup = {
    "var1": var1,
    "var2": var2,
    "var3": var3,
    "var4": var4,
}

def get_var(x):
    return vars_lookup.get(x, x)

eax = get_var(eax)
ebx = get_var(ebx)
ecx = get_var(ecx)
edx = get_var(edx)
```

Note here that the `get` method of the `dict` type works like the usual brackets notation (`vars_lookup[x]`), but handles cases where the key is not found in the dictionary and then returns the default value (the second argument).

Comment: A dictionary (Python hash table) would be faster in execution and more concise to write (especially since in many cases it can be built programmatically as a byproduct of some other necessary process).

Comment: @JamesTollefson, good to note, I've updated the answer to include an approach that uses a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `vars()`

`variable_list = [v for v in [eax, ebx, ecx, edx] if v is not str else vars()[v]]`

or

```
eax = vars()[eax] if eax is not str else eax
ebx = vars()[ebx] if ebx is not str else ebx
ecx = vars()[ecx] if ecx is not str else ecx
edx = vars()[edx] if edx is not str else edx
```

This is only a more "hacky" version, the answer from @Henry Woody is more readable while this being cleaner. I would recommend his over this for the sake of being more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution is to use a dictionary. Simply define it like this:

```py
var_dict = {
    'var1':var1,
    'var2':var2,
    'var3':var3,
    'var4':var4,
    }
```

Then when you find a situation where you need to translate from the string value to the variable, do this:

```py
eax = "var1" #as an example
eax = var_dict[eax] #now eax is the variable var1
```

This will change `eax`, in this case, from `"var1"` to the actual variable itself, `var1`. You could even store functions in your dictionary this way if you so desired. You would simply call them with:

```py
var_dict[eax]()
```